# Why is fs.createWriteStream throwing a "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory" error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, asynchronous, fs

Here is the code:

```
      const dest = fs.createWriteStream('./src/Pages/downloads/' + fileName + '.' + type)

      await drive.files.export({
        fileId: fileId, mimeType: newType}, 
        {responseType: 'stream'},
        function(err, response){
        if(err)return console.log(err);
        response.data.on('error', err => {
            console.log("Found at 911 " + err);
        })
        .pipe(dest, function(){console.log('file path written.')})
        .on('end', ()=>{
            console.log("sent file.")
        })
      });
```

A few things to explain.

1. This is within a post request that takes several variables from a google drive file, such as its name, id, and mimetype. These are the "fileName" and "type" variables that show up within the WriteStream request. They are already predefined and not the problem. So for the sake of this question, assume that the variables are something like var fileName = test, var type = pdf, and var newType = "application/pdf".
2. The drive.files.export function is an asynchronous call to the Google Drive api that finds the file/folder/item with the specific id noted in "fileId" and exports it. What I am trying to achieve here is exporting the file that fits that specific id into the WriteStream as defined by dest.
3. The './src/Pages/downloads/' path does exist. Obviously the particular file (for the test case let's say test.pdf) doesn't yet, but that's why I am using the createWriteStream.
4. I have already tried changing the path from './src/Pages/downloads/' to __dirname + "/src/Pages/downloads" and the same error below occurs.

With all of this said, I get an error that looks like this.

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> './src/Pages/downloads/test.pdf Emitted 'error' event on WriteStream
> instance at: at internal/fs/streams.js:375:14

This error occurs at the const dest = fs.createWriteStream(...) event. Would anyone be able to explain what is going on? Would really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: You might see the directory when you look in your file browser, but `fs` does not see the directory from its perspective. change the path to `./` and see if you still get the error.

Comment: It's already like that in the WriteStream. @RandyCasburn
You do make a good point though. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: No, I meant completely remove every part of the current file path and replace it with only `./`. You might get surprised at where it drops the file :-)

Comment: It seems likely that `'./src/Pages/downloads/'` is not pointing where you expect it to be.  I'd suggest logging this `console.log(path.normalize('./src/Pages/downloads/' + fileName + '.' + type))` and see exactly where it points.  It's probably pointing to a directory that doesn't exist.

Comment: have you tried using path.resolve() ?

Comment: I got this error because the directory did not exist.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, finally I found it's because the filename is not correct, it contains `:`.

My system is windows.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the path was relative (i.e. `"./tmp_folder/1.txt"`) instead of a full path (i.e. `"/Users/name/project_name/tmp_folder/1.txt"`).

This:

```
fs.createWriteStream(path.join('./tmp_folder', fileName), { encoding: 'utf8' });
```

Turned to this (`__dirname` is the difference):

```
fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, './tmp_folder', fileName), { encoding: 'utf8' });
```